# Android background based on screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating an Android application, and want different background images for phone sized screens and tablet sized ones. I already have different resolution images for different resolutions (`mdpi`, `hdpi` etc.). The challenge is that most tablets use `mdpi`, but some phones might use it too.

I've tried to do some research, but only it seems to be possible to define screen sizes in the layouts, e.g. `res/layout/layout-large`. Does that mean I have to create a separate xml for tablets, linking to a `@drawable/tablet-background`? Or is there any other solutions, either xml or programmatic?

Comment: *but only it seems to be possible to define screen sizes in the layouts* - where did you read this?

Comment: [This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) states **Provide different layouts for different screen sizes** *or* **Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities** *not* **Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen sizes**. The rest might just be assumptions.

Comment: Did you tried qualifying it with both dimensions and density(large-mdpi) and failed?

Comment: @Luksprog I never even considered that o_O But it works like a charm. I wonder why Google didn't mention that (or maby I just didn't look hard enough). If you submit it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and want different background images for phone sized screens and
>   tablet sized ones

Try the qualify the `drawable` folder with the desired screen size and also the density value for the target device, for example `drawable-large-mdpi`. The screen size must come first based on the [configuration qualifiers table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Comment: Yay. Thanks. Also supports older devices (I'm aiming for 2.3 support)

Answer (score 3):

*mdpi*, *hpdi* etc. refers to screen density and that's independent from the device being a tablet or a phone. If I understood correctly, what you're trying to do is to use different background images for tablet and for phones.
There are three ways:

1. Create an xml layout for tablet and an xml layout for phone using *layout-large, layout-xlarge* folders
2. Using the same xml layout (except for an element id) in *layout* and in *layout-large* folders and change the background programmatically using something like this:

   ```
   public boolean isTablet(){
       return (findViewById(R.id.tablet_view) != null); 
   }
   ```

   where tablet_view is an element id present only in the *layout-large* xml layout.
3. Another trick: [Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. You shouldn't use `layout-large`, `layout-xlarge` etc. anymore. Instead use  for example `layout-sw600dp` (for 7" tablets). Same goes for the `drawables`. For example: `drawable-sw600dp-hdpi`. So overall a lot easier and no need to change anything programatically.

Comment: why shouldn't use layout-large and layout-xlarge?

Comment: @reVerse Are the `sw600dp` qualifiers working below Honeycomb?

Comment: According to the docs: no, but is there any need for that? Every relevant tablet runs Honeycomb and above as far as I know.
@DavideSilvestri Those size qualifiers are deprecated since API-Level 13