# How can I provide orientation support for tablet alone in android?

Tags: android, orientation, tablet

Hi I am developing an android application for that I want to provide orientation support for android tablets alone, I don't want to give orientation support for phones. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this in two steps.

Step one - determine whether the device is a tablet or a phone. You acomplish this by setting a specific boolean value that will indicate what kind of device you are dealing based on the screen size. The technique for doing this is explained in the android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali) and in another StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)

Step two - if you are dealing with a phone set the orientation in the desired way. You can use

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

This should only set the orientation to the designated way. To keep it in that orientation you need to override how the activity responds to configurations changes.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

By overriding `onConfigurationChanged` you should be able to get the phone to ignore the rotation and allow the tablet to recognize it.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted, and overriding onConfigurationChanged should do the trick thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

simple solution create seperated

> Activity

for tablet and phone

Answer (score 1):

you can do this easily by making a small changes:

First add your xml layout to the following folder:

```
layout-sw600dp //Based upon device size
layout-sw720dp
```

For more information check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)