# Android Universal App Approach

Tags: android-layout, android, apk

I want to develop an universal app . I am novice to this approach .That means a single apk for both tablet and phone application . I had go through

[Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

My aim is to build different UI for Tablet and Phone inside a single APk .

I had read [Getting Your App Ready for Jelly Bean and Nexus 7](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html) . This article mention that

```
res/layout/activity_home.xml

To take advantage of the extra space on the 7” screen you might provide an alternative layout:

res/layout-sw600dp/activity_home.xml

The sw600dp qualifier declares that these resources are for devices that have a screen with at least 600dp available on its smallest side. 

    Furthermore you might even provide a different layout for 10” tablets:

res/layout-sw720dp/activity_home.xml
```

That means we can use different layout for different device . This confuses me

**EDIT 1 :: Scenario**

Suppose

```
if my phone UI layout contains one-view pager and 

tablet UI layout contain two-view pager  .
```

How can we achieve this ?? In this article it says that you an designe different layout with same name for different screen and keep it corresponding folder . But my doubt will this arise exceptions if it try to initialize widget component of Tablet layout when app is running in a phone .

**EDIT 2 :**
The idea came into my mind is determine which type of device is i am using ie Tab or phone .

[Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)

Then avoid the initialization of widgets if app is phone . Is there any better way than this ??

**EDIT 3 :**
My application support from 2.3 to higher versions

If my layouts for tablet holds additional widgets compared to phone layout .How an i initialize and use . Hope all understood my need . So please clarify my doubt

Comment: **That means we can use different layout for different device . This confuses me.** What confuses you? I think you've done loads of research already.

Comment: I preferably use layout/large (for 5.1-7 inch device), layout/xlarge( for 10 inch tabs) and layout normal for mobiles. Mobile layouts can be further defined by using layout/large-xhdpi or ldpi/mdpi/hdpi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I face the problem, I create following structure.

```
res/layout
res/layout-sw600dp
```

then to distinguish values and other resources,

```
res/values
res/values-sw600dp
res/values-sw720dp
```

You noticed that there is only **one layout** directory and **two values** directory to specify margins and paddings and other resources. So single layout can be used for 7" as well 10" tablet. This is my scenario, you can also define **layout-sw720dp**. I did that due to reduce compilation time of layouts.

I have also different layouts in phone and tablet. For example, I have a **ListView** in first screen, then when user click on item, it will open other activity and there is **DetailView** for that. But in tablet, I have left side **ListView** and right side **DetailView**.

So to do so, in **values/strings**, I place following code,

```
<bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
```

and same for tablet **values-sw600dp/strings**

```
<bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
```

Now, come to part of coding. I have a splash screen and which has common layout. So it will display common screen. But when user click on any button, it will check whether it is **tablet** or not. To check it,

```
boolean isTablet = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
```

You have now flag indicate whether your application is running on **phone** or **tablet**.

I have created two packages,

```
com.phone
com.tablet
```

then as per **flag**, I direct my activity to **phone** package and **tablet** package.

Example,

```
if(isTablet)
    startActivity(this,TabXYZ.class);
else
    startActivity(this,PhXYZ.class);
```

And this approach has solved my problem.

Comment: So you are telling me to use two layout handler class for one functionality

Comment: But that functionality will be different if screens are different my friend. If functionality is same, then go for fragment, it will solve your problem, but though i have problem with screen design different for both phone and tablet, i use this approach.

Comment: I considered your answer.. But still looking is there any other way to handle this

Comment: Refering some article shows sw600dp qualifier is only valid for platforms above android 3.2 .My application supports from 2.3 . what was your case??

Comment: I have created my application in 2.3.3 (Ginger Bread). No issue right now. And is also on play store.

Comment: If you want to check, download and try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.heliumcreative.bluemartini&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd

Comment: @edwin, if your problem solved with answer, please mark accepted so other can get benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` will return the widget in case it's present in the layout, `null` in case there's no such widget. So if it returns non-null you can proceed with further initialization.

Comment: I've seen they sometimes do like this: if you know that on a certain layout you have more widgets than on another layout then you can just check for the presence of a single widget from that 'extra' group. If findViewById gives non-null it means you will also have all the rest of your extra widgets.