# Tab-bar Settings as overlay in tablet?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using Android action bar to show settings as follow in phone version.

[image]

when i click on settings it will call SettingsActivity, However in Tablet version i have to show Settings in a different format like below.

[image]

Here **Settings icon should open as a drawer overlay(over any screen) with settings.** How to achieve this? Is there any controls for showing these kind of overlay? The inside settings page contains other controls like spinner, switch etc.

Comment: That doesn't sound too right: you're opening the settings activity which has a settings menu item which you want to click to get other settings?

Comment: No. In tablet you click settings icon on action bar it opens a overlay as shown in tablet image, which will contain all the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), and then [detect if the user is using a tablet or a smartphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet). If it's a tablet, open a [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) with the Fragment inside, if it's a smartphone, open a FragmentActivity with the same Fragment inside. You could also customize the fragment to look slightly differently in the different cases using the `layout` folders.