# How to find an android appliction running in 7 inches or 10 inches Tab?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to find my app running in 7 inches tab or 10 inches tab.How i can find it.please can any one help me.

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: You mean on what size of screen your application is running?

Answer (score 2):

Create a bool value  in the values - sw600 and sw 720 as

in sw600
 isSevenInch - true;
 isTenInch - false;

in sw720
 isTenInch - true;
 isSevenInch - false;

and at runtime get the bool value and u can find that u required.

From [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308284/1937802)

Answer (score 1):

once try this

```
Display deviceDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = deviceDisplay.getWidth();
int height = deviceDisplay.getHeight();

DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double xPoints = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
double yPoints = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi,2);
double deviceScreenSizeInInch = Math.sqrt(xPoints+yPoints);
```

Comment: How i can check is it running in 7 inches or 10 inches tab?

Comment: check updated ans jst nw checeked(in emulator) value for deviceScreenSizeInInch = 7.270660324187946 for 7 inch & for 10 inch it will gve value accordingly not exact 10 bt it will near by . int cast and all may req... hope ths will help