# Set portrait for phone but both portrait and landscape orientation for tablet

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-orientation

I just had a basic question regarding the orientation. Currently my app just supports phones in portrait mode only. I just altered it to support tablets, but I am wondering how I can make it work for both orientations for tablet, keeping the phone orientation to portrait. Here is part of the code in my manifest for setting it to portrait:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" android:path="/msf1.0/public/mobilebootstrapper.aspx"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` ine the onCreate method of your Activity if the device is a phone. To determine if the device is a phone or a tablet, you can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet).

Comment: so I basically set setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR); for tablet?

Comment: If you want the device to recognize orientation based on the orientation sensor, you need to set it to ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR. All constants are explained here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation

Comment: what do i do with the screenorientation defined in manifest as portrait?

Comment: You could remove it for that activity node.

Comment: If you open your application in Landscape in Phone, then the app opens in landscape mode and then shifts to Portrait Mode. This does not solve the issue completely