# When does the system use the ActionBar height for the tablet

Tags: android, android-resources

I need to create a dimension that should be used only in the case that the system uses the **`ActionBar` height** for the tablet.

Does anyone know when the system think it is on a tablet and then uses this specific ActionBar height?

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This answers your question [Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as a 'tablet' from the system's point of view. It's just a larger screen device, and such we can use a larger height.

To put it simply, you shouldn't need to know when this happens. Just use the code from @sarbjot

To give you a full answer we currently use:

```
default (portrait): 56dp
landscape: 48dp
sw600dp: 64dp
```

Comment: Ok the sw600dp was what I was looking for. Thnaks a lot.