# Change imageView params in all cards together

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-rotation

I'm using `RecyclerView` and in its `Adapter` each list item has image and some text inside a `CardView`.

**Question :** I want to change the weight of each `ImageView` programmatically.

This is the code that runs on screen rotation:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        SquareImageView imgView = (SquareImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imgView.getLayoutParams();
        lp.weight = 0.1f;
    }
}
```

The code runs but just on one card and not on all cards.

Edit:
My Adapter code if needed:

```
// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, LinkedList<CardData> myDataset)
{
    mContext = context;
    mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    // create a new view
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_card_view, parent, false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(parent.getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            Not Relevant
        });

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }});

    return viewHolder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    CardData currentCard = mDataset.get(position);

    holder.mHeadline.setText(currentCard.mHeadline);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the actual way of changing the layout items in the list items in your `RecyclerView` in `onConfigurationChanged`

You need to modify your adapter code and [check if the orientation is tablet or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308284/3145960).

So inside your adapter you need to set the layout weight with something like this in your `onBindViewHolder`

```
if(tablet){
    lp.weight = 0.1f;
} else {
    lp.weight = 1; // Whatever
}
```

Now in `onConfigurationChanged` you just need to reset your adapter.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Reset your adapter here.
    myAdapter.resetAdapter();
}
```

Comment: Where exactly in the Adapter? OnBindViewHolder or OnCreateViewHolder? Thanks!

Comment: I read it, but couldn't find anything related to the adapter. moreover, there is no such function resetAdapter.

Comment: `resetAdapter` is a function you need to write in your adapter. This function will simply reset the views calling `notifyDatasetChanged`. But anyway, try without declaring a `resetAdapter`. The `Adapter` should reset the views automatically. Tell me if it doesn't update the views. Post your adapter code and I'll look into your adapter too.

Comment: I tried to add this to my adapter: `LinearView.LayoutParams lp = (LinearView.LayoutParams) holder.mLayout.getLayoutParams();` but it doesn't work. Do you know why? and why is it better to check if tablet and not the orientation?