# Android - How to lock orientation for different device?

Tags: android, locking, orientation, landscape, portrait

I am trying to lock the phone to portrait and tablet to landscape.
I usually use AndroidManifest.xml - android:screenOrientation="portrait"
But how can I set orientation to tablet / phone differently?
Thanks!

Comment: Wild guess: make 2 distinct apps?

Comment: @Rotwang 2 distinct apps is a very lame solution

Comment: @deadfish But that's the way they do it on iDevices. Then, are all Apple-centric developers `lamers`?

Comment: I like the way you think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to load one parameter from res folder from specific value. So if Your app is running on tablet, the screen density must be great or equals to 600dp.

In folder: res/values-sw600dp/ create xml with param:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

In folder res/values/ create xml with param

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

After that You will be able check if app is running on tablet or phone by using this code:

```
boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
if (tabletSize) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
} else {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Source from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308284/619673

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: So there is no way to set it in xml?

Comment: values from res folder can be used after run app, imho not before. Thanks to multiple naming folders in res folder i.e values-sw600dp or values-landscape You can handle only specific situation. Answer I gave You is imho the best and safe.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether device is smartphone or tablet then you can set the orientation of your activity by using below code

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

and you can check  [Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)

Answer (score 0):

First you can detect whether your app is running on smartphone or a tablet for that please see following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308284/3640881)

Now you can lock orientation using following code:

```
If(isTablet)
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
else
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Java code. In java class that you want to make special orientation, use this code:

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) ==
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
        // on a X large screen device ...
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) ==
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
        // on a large screen device ...
        // do everythings you want to do ...
    } else {
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

and in fragment use "getActivity()" instead of "this". And for make view flexible with device use this code:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Maybe worked. Good luck.