# Xamarin UITest - determine if device is Phone or Tablet for Android?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-test-cloud, xamarin.uitest

Is there a way to determine if the Android device I'm running tests on is Phone or Tablet? Found various answers on this topic from an Android development perspective, but I'm just developing tests and looking for some method from Xamarin.UITest that could tell me this. For the iOS there is a built-in method like app.Device.IsPhone, but I can't seem to find something similar for the Android.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9308284/7410353

Comment: [Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)

Answer (score 2):

The way that I do it in my tests is check the size of the device see code below:

```
public bool DeviceIsTablet()
    {
        var screen = app.Query(x => x.Id("content"));
        var height = screen.FirstOrDefault().Rect.Height;
        var width = screen.FirstOrDefault().Rect.Width;
        if (width < 1600 || height > 1850)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What would you say are the correct numbers then Mina Fawzy?