# Android - How to set visibility in xml depending on device?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, android-resources

I have a `TextView` in my activity that should be `visible` normally, but `gone` for tablet devices.

I know I can create a new layout file for the tablet, but that seems like a lot of duplication, so what I am trying to do is set in my (single) layout file something like...

`android:visibility="@string/my_textview_visibility"`

...for the `TextView`. And then, in my strings resources files, set...

`<string name="my_textview_visibility">gone</string>` (in **values/strings.xml**)

...and...

`<string name="my_textview_visibility">visible</string>` (in **values-sw720dp/strings.xml**)

...to hide the TextView for tablets.

However, when I try this, the app crashes when trying to show that activity.

Do I need to use the constant values instead of the above string values - e.g.,

`"visible"` -> `0`

`"gone"` -> `8`

..and, if so, what is the correct way to add/reference those values to/from my XML files?

Or is there another/better way of doing it?

NB - I do not want to show/hide the `TextView` programatically in my Java code.

Comment: any reason why you dont want to do it programatically ? Because its very simple .

Comment: Yes, I would rather control all my layouts from XML and keep the Java separate, where possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using `/values/integers/` instead:

**values/integers.xml**

```
<integer name="my_textview_visibility">0</integer> <!-- 0 = View.VISIBLE -->
```

**values-sw720dp/integers.xml**

```
<integer name="my_textview_visibility">2</integer> <!-- 2 = View.GONE -->
```

Then called like so:

```
android:visibility="@integer/my_textview_visibility"
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completion, you don't have to use `/values/integers/` nor `strings.xml`. You just need to define an android resource of type `integer`

Comment: Conventionally, where is the best place to declare these integers?

Comment: I don't think there's a convention. A good idea might be having an `values/integers.xml` file with all your integers, similar to what is usually done with `values/strings.xml`.

Answer (score 6):

ChrisStillwell's answer is correct. But the values are incorrect according to the Android Documentation

[image]

Comment: You are correct, the `8` value in my original answer gives an error. I didn't bother checking the values, just went off on what OP said. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I got the `8` from here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE

Comment: I see, but you wanna use the attribute value and not the java constant value. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the best way to do this is to create a specific `layout` for `tablets` where your `TextView` will be hidden. However, it is possible to do this using `xml boolean resources` : (as `res/values-sw600dp/`):

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Because the `sw600dp` qualifier is only valid for platforms above android 3.2. If you want to make sure this technique works on all platforms (before 3.2), create the same file in `res/values-xlarge` folder:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Then, in the "standard" value file (as `res/values/`), you set the boolean to false:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Then in you activity, you can get this value and check if you are running in a tablet size device:

```
boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
if (tabletSize) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Font : [Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)

Comment: The question clearly states: `NB - I do not want to show/hide the TextView programatically in my Java code.`