# Xamarin UI Test - different element selectors for Phone / Tablet

Tags: xamarin, device-detection

I am looking at Xamarin UI test as a POC for a native Android and iOS app. Not used Xamarin before or C, so I am bluffing my way through at the moment.  I have managed to get it running on the Android Phone version of the app, but how do I make it clever enough to look for different elements between the Phone / Tablet implementation?  Going further I will be trying to make the POC cross platform so will need to take into account the platform too.

I have seen references to platform and idiom but not sure how to use them in the Tests.cs file.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try the way below to determine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet/9308284#9308284