# Pixel 7 pro android 13 - getting the wrong resource

Tags: android, pixel, android-13

I have an application for tablet and mobile, and to recognize if it's tablet or mobile I set a boolean value in a specific value file (similar to this example: [Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)). for some reason, the pixel 7 pro (with android 13) is not getting this value correctly and recognizes it as a tablet. It's important to note that the activities' layout files are taken correctly.

Does somebody know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `DeviceProperties.isTablet(applicationContext)` from `com.google.android.gms.common.util.DeviceProperties` and my Pixel 6 Pro is recognized as phone.
It should also work for Pixel 7 Pro.