# How can I Implement method isMyDeviceATablet()?

Tags: java, android

I want to check if my device is a tablet or not.

What is the best implementation of method isMyDeviceATablet() or isMyDeviceATablet(Context context)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android

Comment: ^ The top answer on that post seems kinda iffy, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Google I/O 2011 app:

```
public static boolean isHoneycomb() {
    // Can use static final constants like HONEYCOMB, declared in 
    // later versions of the OS since they are inlined at compile 
    // time. This is guaranteed behavior.
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
}

public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}

public static boolean isHoneycombTablet(Context context) {
    return isHoneycomb() && isTablet(context);
}
```