# Android 4.0+ tablet keyword?

Tags: android

I heard that there is a keyword or method that Android developers can use to determine whether  Android 4.0+ is running on a tablet (without having to do any kludgy screen size comparisons). I can't find it.

So, is this true? If so, what is it?

Edit: I see that people are giving me answers that are not what I'm looking for. I already know how to determine whether a device is a tablet or phone using the kludgy screen size method and using the OS method. I'm looking for a method that has been available starting with API level 14 that will tell me the same information -- hopefully. I can't find it, so I'm wondering whether it even exists.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 4+ has the [configuration object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html). You can use the "isLayoutSizeAtLeast(int size)" method to do your check. It's less kludgy than some other examples I've seen around.

Comment: This is closer to the answer that I'm looking for

Comment: That's exactly the same as what I posted, and it's been available since API 1, though the specific method was introduced in 11 (Android 3.0).

Comment: Ralgha's right, this is the same answer. If I remember he beat me to it by 2 minutes (his post went up while I was finding the link).

Answer (score 1):

Tablet basically just means a big(er) screen, so it comes down to that.  There's an easy way of seeing if it's a tablet sized screen or not:

```
if ( getResources().getConfiguration().isLayoutSizeAtLeast( Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE ) )
{
    //Is a tablet.
}
```

You could change `Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE` to `Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE` if you want to catch smaller ones too.

Comment: I actually explicitly asked for the capability in Android 4+. I also explicitly said that I didn't want the solution that involves screen size comparisons.

Comment: You said you didn't want "kludgy" screen size comparisons.  Though "kludgy" is subjective, most people would probably agree that this method is not "kludgy."  Android 4+ is capable of doing this.  If you also want to know if it is Android 4+, then you can do `if ( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 )`.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the android documentation, the SDK level (integer) the phone is running is available in:

android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

The enum corresponding to this int is in the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES class.

Code example:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
    // Do something for froyo and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
}
```

Edit: This SDK_INT is available since Donut (android 1.6 / API4) so make sure your application is not retro-compatible with Cupcake (android 1.5 / API3) when you use it or your application will crash (thanks to Programmer Bruce for the precision).

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically)