# Lock device orientation - React Native (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, orientation, device-orientation

I'm using React Native 0.29 and developing for Android. I'm trying to lock the device orientation. What I need is to lock the screen in portrait mode. I tried with this repository https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation but it is not supporting RN 0.29 yet.

Is there any way I can lock the device orientation? Maybe any native Android hack with android studio?

Answer (score 27):

Just add android:screenOrientation="portrait" to the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: The how to add see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718869/how-to-lock-android-apps-orientation-to-portrait-mode

Comment: android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml in a react-native project

Answer (score 3):

### 2017 Update

Currently, there is also another way to do it once for both Android and iOS by adding:

#### `"orientation": "portrait"`

in `app.json` if you're using Expo:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My app",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "sdkVersion": "21.0.0",
    "privacy": "public",
    "orientation": "portrait"
  }
}
```

Or at runtime:

#### `ScreenOrientation.allow()`

Example:

```
ScreenOrientation.allow(ScreenOrientation.Orientation.PORTRAIT);
```

Note that it only works if you're building with Expo but since this is currently (as of 2017) recommended in official guides on [React Native Blog](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/) then probably a lot of people are using it so it's worth mentioning as an interesting solution in addition to hacking the Android-specific XML configuration files.

### More info:

For more info see:
**[how to disable rotation in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176548/how-to-disable-rotation-in-react-native/46671734#46671734)**

Answer (score 2):

There is a pull request for this to work on 0.29.2 and above:
https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation/pull/85

If you use his version, it should work on 0.29.2 and above:
https://github.com/youennPennarun/react-native-orientation

Steps:

1. unlink the previous installation with `rnpm unlink react-native-orientation`
2. `rm -rf node_modules/react-native-orientation`
3. in your package.json edit the entry of `react-native-orientation` to be as:

   `"react-native-orientation": "youennPennarun/react-native-orientation"`
4. `npm install`
5. `react-native link react-native-orientation`

Things should work after this. You can track the progress of the PR and switch to main repo when it has been merged.

Answer (score 0):

react-native-orientation - is no longer compatible with new version (I have tried 0.39.2). After linking this module I have the compiler's error.
As I got it, now we should use [react-native-orientation-listener](https://github.com/walmartlabs/react-native-orientation-listener)

**npm install --save react-native-orientation-listener

rnpm link**

Comment: I don't really know. I ran into strange issue with this module. Either it's my lack of experience with React or it's buggy... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407229/react-native-orientation-listener-cannot-read-property-getorientation-of-undef

Answer (score 0):

**Step:1**

```
npm install git+https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation.git --save
```

**Step2:**
    react-native link
**Step:3**
*Modify the MainApplication.java file with:*

```
import com.github.yamill.orientation.OrientationPackage;// import

@Override
protected List getPackages() {
return Arrays.asList(
new MainReactPackage(),
new OrientationPackage() //add this
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-orientation-locker](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker).

The 'react-native-orientation' has been deprecated.
Using the 'react-native-orientation-locker' component, you would be able to detect the current orientation, as well as locking it to Portrait/Landscape by using:

```
Orientation.lockToPortrait();

Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft();
```

Even release the locks using

```
Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
```