# How to lock orientation in react-native page

Tags: react-native

i have multiple pages in my react-native project. i have designed all pages for Portrait mode but i need only one page for video in Landscape mode. How i can do this?

I have tried react-native-orientation. Its not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock device orientation - React Native (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622268/lock-device-orientation-react-native-android)