# how to disable rotate in android ? how to add sensor portrait to manifest ? how to fix layout in landspace?

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, autorotate, screen-rotation

i know its a noob question but i am new in android development and i dont want my app rotate in landspace.
according to some of questions i found sensor portrait. i tried to add it in manifest but i dont know where.
 if its not working is there any source code to disable rotate?
i am really need help my layout looks owful in landspace.
i dont know how to fix the background
what can i do to fix layout in landspace?
what should i do?
i didnt find the answer in question.
thanks

1. How to use sensorportrait?
2. source code for disable rotate?
3. fix layout in landspace?

i really dont want the answer for thirdone but its a good point for a app to work in portrait and landspace.

Comment: This is two separate questions.

Comment: each one of them will solve my problem

Comment: I do not know what sensor patriot is. Will post an answer shortly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lock android app's orientation to portrait mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718869/how-to-lock-android-apps-orientation-to-portrait-mode)

Comment: Actually, the question is already answered. Just replace "portrait" with "landscape".

Comment: yeah i found it the answer from edguar luca i have to add sensor before the patriot.thanks guys

Comment: but there is one more problem

Comment: how can i change a orientation in diferent activities? i should add it to all?

Comment: ok.i will go for it thanks guys.

Comment: Yes, you have to set the orientation for every activity

Comment: Its PORTRAIT not patriot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this document, it explains each property in your AndroidManifest.xml. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

1. How to use sensorportrait?

   > These Properties are defined in your AndroidManifest.xml file.
   >
   > android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "behind" |
   >                                        "landscape" | "portrait" |
   >                                        "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
   >                                        "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
   >                                        "userLandscape" | "userPortrait" |
   >                                        "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor" |
   >                                        "user" | "fullUser" | "locked"]
2. source code for disable rotate?

   > In your AndroidManifest.xml file, where you define "activity", u set orientation you support as defined above.
3. fix layout in landspace?

   > You can have different layout for your activity in landscape mode. for this simply create `layout-land` folder parallel to `layout` folder in `res`. 
   >   e.g. if you have `activity_main.xml` in `layout` folder, create another `activity_main.xml` in `layout-land` folder. You can move stuff around as you wish. Note: I would reccomend you take a look at `Fragments`, this might help you on what you are trying to achieve.
   >   https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add this code in your manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

**screenOrientation = "landscape"** is force screen to landscape

Comment: so when i put phone in reverse will the screen rotate to reverse patriot?

Comment: @MohammadRezaMajidPour what do you mean by "put the phone in reverse" and "reverse patriot"? I do not know what these are.

Comment: @MohammadRezaMajidPour Are you using google translate?

Comment: @MohammadRezaMajidPour Instead of "patriot" the word you want is "portrait". Also if you write "sensorPortrait" instead of "sensor portrait" it is clear you are using a variable name instead of regular words.

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically change the orientation of the activity, call the `setRequestedOrientation(int)` method.
More info on the method can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)).

The `int` argument sent in method can be changed and fixed. The relevant values for the same can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#screenOrientation).

Comment: its not error my client doesnt have permission to open the link can you add some related values to your answer

Answer (score 0):

For preventing the rotation of your activity, you can also set the orientation in your `onCreate`. It checks your orientation and if it's `LANDSCAPE` it will change it.

Example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
  if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
        Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  }
}
```