# SurfaceView rotation issue on Android 6

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I have a simple activity running my OpenCV application. The app should detect objects from camera and visualize them on a custom SurfaceView. I want to lock the device orientation in portrait mode and rotate my widgets programmatically as the standard camera app does.

Here is the activity layout. It includes OpenCV CameraView and a fragment widget shown above it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.chessking.android.vision.ui.widget.ExtendedCameraView
        android:id="@+id/track_camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        opencv:camera_id="any"
        opencv:show_fps="true"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/track_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/track_board_preview"
            class="com.chessking.android.vision.ui.BoardWidgetFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/track_action"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@string/scan_action"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom `SurfaceView` is presented in the fragment layout. It is `com.convekta.android.chessboard.ChessPanel`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/board_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/boardBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/widget_board_clock_both" />

    <com.convekta.android.chessboard.ChessPanel
        android:id="@+id/board_panel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/board_background_transparent"
        app:chessPanelBackground="@color/board_background_transparent"
        app:chessPanelBorderColor="@color/board_border"
        app:chessPanelBorderWidth="1dp"/>

    <com.convekta.android.chessboard.NotationView
        android:id="@+id/nota"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I need to rotate the widget layour, I change `rotation` property of the `board_layout`.

```
boardLayout.rotation = degrees.toFloat()
```

The problem is the rotation works on Android 9, but the canvas is misplaced on Android. Here are screenshots from Android 6 emulator, in portrait mode the app looks normal, in landscape SurfaceView jumps out of its layout.[image: Portrait mode]
[image: Landscape mode]

Comment: There is an answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718869/how-to-lock-android-apps-orientation-to-portrait-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718869/how-to-lock-android-apps-orientation-to-portrait-mode)

Answer (score 1):

In the `<activity>` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`, add the line `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Comment: I already locked it. I need the activity to be locked, while the fragment can be rotated. As far as I searched it, I need to rotate the fragment programmatically. I've done this, but it doesn't work with SurfaceView on Android 6..