# Portrait workbench in landscape mode

Tags: android, landscape

Hope someone can tell me in which file and location I can set this;

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:exported="false"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|locale|keyboardHidden|uiModel"
android:screenOrientation="locked"
```

I'm not familiar with android, but i have same problem or at least very similar on RPI4 running AOST Android 13 by Konstakang. Walpaper, control buttons rotate properly, fill all the screen as should but "main" window is portrait oriented on landscape screen of 1280x400 resolution. Icons are though useless. Help would be very appreciated! Thanks Gregor

Tried all possible standard settings, but no luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Those tags belong to the [app manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) (AndroidManifest.xml), you would set them inside the `activity` tag (like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15718909/15749574)