# in android how to set condition for whether is phone or tablet?

Tags: android, navigation, conditional-statements, tablet

Here is my code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

It is for phone. In tablet, I don't want to show "Up button" on navigation. But how programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate 


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found it. Adding a boolean to the resource according to size of the activity is just fine.

```
boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && !tabletSize) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
```