# How to check whether a device is tablet or handset for all devices programmatically

Tags: android

How to check Whether a device is tablet or handset for all devices and OS(2.2-latest) programmatically.

Comment: check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5832368)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. You can set a boolean inside res/values

```
<bool name="isHandest">false</bool>
```

inside `values-sw600dp`, `values-sw720dp` and `values-xlarge`

and

```
<bool name="isHandest">true</bool>
```

in `res/values`

Comment: what about tablet 7 inch running 3.0 OS, this will not work

Comment: It should be on values-large. Imho a 7" with android lower.than 3.2 it is not a tablet

Answer (score 0):

Use the Smallest-width Qualifier:

> The Smallest-width qualifier allows you to target screens that have a
>   certain minimum width given in dp. For example, the typical 7" tablet
>   has a minimum width of 600 dp, so if you want your UI to have two
>   panes on those screens (but a single list on smaller screens), you can
>   use the same two layouts from the previous section for single and
>   two-pane layouts, but instead of the large size qualifier, use sw600dp
>   to indicate the two-pane layout is for screens on which the
>   smallest-width is 600 dp

You can use different layouts or set a boolean in these folders:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="is_tablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

From official doc:
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: but if the OS is less than 3.2 its useless

Answer (score -1):

If you define tablet as device with screen bigger than 7"

```
public static boolean isTablet() {
    return screenSize >= 7;
}

public static double getScreenSize(Activity activity){
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
    double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi,2);
    screenSize = Math.sqrt(x+y);        
    return screenSize;
}
```

Comment: I believe "smallest width" resources qualifier like sw600dp  does not work for Android version below 3.2? I cannot use layout-large as devices with screen size 5.4, 5.8, 6.3 fall into that category as well (while the first Samsung Galaxy Tab thinks it has normal layout). This is the problem I face in my project, beside calculating the screen size, no other way works for me.