# How to judge whether the Android device is phone or pad?

Tags: android

How to judge whether the Android device is phone or pad,I can not find some method of Android API.Now I judge it based on device dimensions, if(size > 6) -->pad  else ---> phone,does it have another solution

Comment: Is this to determine how to set the `layout`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tablet or Phone - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android)

Comment: Is this a layout issue or just trying to check if the device is having phone call functionality or not?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android

Answer (score 5):

I know this is not what you want to hear, but you don't distinguish between phone or tablet.

You need to ask yourself, why?

- There are 7inch + devices with phone functionality.

- There are 5inch - devices without phone functionality.

- Sensors vary between devices, large and small.

- There are phablets which may fall into either category.

So, if my definition of a "phone" is, "can it make phone calls?" then ...

```
TelephonyManager manager = 
        (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if(manager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE)
{ // it has no phone 
}
```

Comment: I think some tablet also can make phone calls

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that you can check if the device is a tablet.

```
/**
 * Checks if the device is a tablet or a phone
 * 
 * @param activityContext
 *            The Activity Context.
 * @return Returns true if the device is a Tablet
 */
public static boolean isTabletDevice(Context activityContext) {
    // Verifies if the Generalized Size of the device is XLARGE to be
    // considered a Tablet
    boolean xlarge = ((activityContext.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
                        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
                        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE);

    // If XLarge, checks if the Generalized Density is at least MDPI
    // (160dpi)
    if (xlarge) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        Activity activity = (Activity) activityContext;
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        // MDPI=160, DEFAULT=160, DENSITY_HIGH=240, DENSITY_MEDIUM=160,
        // DENSITY_TV=213, DENSITY_XHIGH=320
        if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT
                || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH
                || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM
                || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV
                || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {

            // Yes, this is a tablet!
            return true;
        }
    }

    // No, this is not a tablet!
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wow, shamelessly stolen answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way to scale bitmaps and such in a gaming sense is to figure out roughly what percentage of the screen u want ur images to take up for example if i have a player and i have an image of 256x256 resolution and i was in portrait mode and i wanted the image to take up roughly 33% of the screens width, i scale the image by that percentage of the screens width rather than a hard coded value, then everything resizes no matter what screen you are on. code for example:

```
private RectF rect;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private int width;

CritterPlayer(Context context, int screenX, int screenY){
    rect = new RectF();

    //percentage of screen
    width = screenX / 3;

//load bitmap
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.player);

//scale bitmap
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
            width,
            width,
            false);
//get center
    x = (screenX - bitmap.getWidth()) / 2;
    y = (screenY - bitmap.getHeight()) / 2;

}
```