# Android lock screen rotation

Tags: android, rotation

I know that I can set the screen layout to portrait or landscape in my activity's xml tag in the manifest to prevent the screen from rotation.

I have an app which shall run on a phone and on a tablet. On the tablet I want to have landscape and on the phone I want to have portrait mode. How can I do this configuration? (And of course when the device rotates the screen shall not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For check whether its a tab or not, you can use this simple method:

```
public boolean isTablet(Context context){
boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
return (xlarge || large);
}
```

OR

```
      public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
      return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
        & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
        >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
      }
```

Both are helpful for you.

For more information, check this [conversation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Let me try to be a bit clearer. The main question was how to lock the screen. Do I have to do that in code (I think I know the code for this) or is there a way to do it in the manifest that I don't have to do it in code? (This I wouldn't know how to do, but is what I prefer even for the complete app not only single activities, but I can do it simply for all activites as well)

Comment: why not you create a class by extend the Application and do everything for total application what you want.i think for this you have to customize your manifest a little.