# Nexus 10 doesn't act like a tablet

Tags: android, android-emulator, tablet

my problem is that emulated in Android Studio Nexus 10 doesn't acts like a phone. I have tried 2 methods to detect is the device a tablet or phone:

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
        & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
        >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

and the variant from here [Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)
Both doesn't work with nexus 10 while working with nexus 7 and another tablet. May be it is the problem of emulator, I dont know. Help me with this please.

Answer (score 0):

This is the old way of tablet determination.  Just to point out what is going wrong, you arent checking if the device is XLARGE (which the n10 is).  A more correct version of this outdated way is :
(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9590506/794088)

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE);
    boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
    return (xlarge || large);
}
```

But instead of this,  please follow this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14370196/794088