# Android detect if hardware speakerphone exist

Tags: android

I am trying to check if my android is tablet or not by detecting if it has speakerphone.
please help.

```
public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE);
boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
return (xlarge || large);}
```

In samsung SGH I527M phone the method return true and its **not** a tablet.
As I mantioned I just wanted to see if the device has earphone to listen through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tablet or Phone - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android)

Comment: Checking for speakerphone isn't a reliable way to tell about tablets. The question of detecing a tablet is extensively discussed e.g. in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android and other articles here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution! Because thats check if it has radio phone so literaly if tou has radio tou have earphone.[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041710/5904387)