# How to detect tablet or smartphone using tablet()?

Tags: android

I am stuck while detecting tablet or smartphone. I have the application that should work on tablet as well as phone. I am not able to conclude how to code to detect the device. I have created the layouts for both tablet and phone. 
I want to use is `Tablet()`.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195083/taven-at-stackoverflow @Shruti

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tablet or Phone - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android)

Answer (score 0):

**values/string.xml**

```
<bool name="is_tablet">false</bool>
```

**values/sw900dp/sting.xml** 
or 
 `values/sw600dp/string.xml`
or
 `values/sw720dp/string.xml`

```
<bool name="is_tablet">true</bool>
```

**check this;**

```
 boolean isTablet = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet);
```

If it's " `dimen`", you can put it in dimen.