# Android : How set force device orientation by device type (tablet, phone)?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to set force orientation device based on the type of the device for using related view (landscape view for tablets and portrait for the mobile devices) rotation cannot be changed on device.

Because i would like to set orientation for all activities during the start of the app i thought that i should to recognize device type in the main activity which is extended by the other activities  related with views.

How can i do it in the right way please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Portrait for phone, landscape for Tablet (Android-Layout)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668367/portrait-for-phone-landscape-for-tablet-android-layout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this in your main activity(Launcher activity) or in Application class,

```
if (isTablet(mContext))
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
            else
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
            return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                    >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
        }
```

Comment: I quess that it should be in Application, rather than main activity... (if you use application context)...

Comment: @Madhur, do you mean I should use above code in MainApplication.java file? (I'm working on a React Native project)
And in your above code, are there any variables declared or used which I need to import too?

Answer (score 2):

Check documentation here http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Multiple APK support could be used for that. But it is BIG weapon for such (seems to be) tiny request.

Basically, you are able to filter target devices in manifest file with `<supports-screens>` element and than define `android:screenOrientation`. So, what you need is separate APK for separate devices.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer from [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627774/android-allow-portrait-and-landscape-for-tablets-but-force-portrait-on-phone):

Here's a good way using [resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Bool) and [size qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers).

Put this bool resource in res/values as bools.xml or whatever (file names don't matter here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="portrait_only">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Put this one in res/values-sw600dp and res/values-xlarge:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="portrait_only">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Then, in the onCreate method of your Activities you can do this:

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Devices that are more than 600 dp in the smallest width direction, or x-large on pre-Android 3.2 devices (tablets, basically) will behave like normal, [based on sensor and user-locked rotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation), etc. Everything else (phones, pretty much) will be portrait only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have fixed orientation for your activities then you can use in your manifest.xml

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait" or 
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

if you don't want it fixed then you can use the following code to get screen size

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

and accordingly

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```