# How to display a 1-inch line on mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, css, ios, mobile-safari

I'm desigining a mobile website for a hamburger parlor. They have varying width of hamburgers, from 3 inches to 3 feet in diameter (no kidding).

Of course, people don't expect a "normal size" hamburger to be 10 inches large (which is!), and they expect the here-usual 3-5 inches.

So what I'd like to do is to display one or two inches on the screen (Android and iOS), and a meter under the picture of the hamburger.

I don't want to build a mobile app if possible, just a "mobile edition" of a webpage.

Any ideas?

Comment: Android devices usually don't know their own exact (or correct) dpi details of the screen so you basically can't show an exact 1 inch line here.

Comment: @zapl: and am I able to "sniff" the exact machine somehow? Like, something which sends me back: "Samsung Galaxy S II", or similar, so I could compare with a DB?

Comment: Since hamburgers aren't exact (especially after being cooked), this should work for you: [Is there a way to determine android physical screen height in cm or inches?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2193457/1267661)

Comment: @Sam exactly that method is what I meant :) [DisplayMetrics xdpi and ydpi returning incorrect values](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/g56jV0Hora0)

Comment: @Sam: I have two problems: 1) I'd like to avoid app-creation, as either then it's just a browser for a single technical feature or we have "how-to-update" problems, and also there's a hassle with the Market / AppStore 2) the country is literally full of ZTE Blades, which are known to report size incorrectly