# How to Support Orientation in android according to different screen sizes?

Tags: android

How to support Landscape and portrait for smartphone which is having screen size more-than 5-inches and only support Portrait mode which is having screen size Less-than or Equal 5-Inches in android.

Thanks,
Android Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193457/is-there-a-way-to-determine-android-physical-screen-height-in-cm-or-inches) before showing every activity (in activity's `onCreate` method). If it is less that 5 inch set activity orientation to [portrait manually](http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/solved-set-screen-orientation-programmatically/).