# How to get exact density value for my device?

Tags: android

I am using DisplayMetrics to get device density but it is not returning the exact value for device density i.e if density is 149 it returns 160. I need this density to find my device actual size in inches. My straight question is to find the exact value i.e 149 not 160.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193457/is-there-a-way-to-determine-android-physical-screen-height-in-cm-or-inches I think its 100% right.

Comment: Actually I used this solution for me but it didn't work well on some devices as explained by me. So its not duplicate :)

Comment: It's still a duplicate _question_ if the answer isn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

From inside an activity:

```
float density = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```