# How I can get the current size screen through of programming?

Tags: android, imageview

I would like get the current size screen inch at the Android to choose a image appropriate for each screen, because my imageview current is larger at the some screens! Is there something method to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this :

[Is there a way to determine android physical screen height in cm or inches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193457/is-there-a-way-to-determine-android-physical-screen-height-in-cm-or-inches)

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
    double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi,2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
    Log.d("debug","Screen inches : " + screenInches);
```

Comment: Rather than copying an existing answer, the question should have been flagged as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the documentation of Android

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html