# Get physical display size in inch, Android?

Tags: android, dimension, android-windowmanager

Is there any way to get physical height and width of screen grammatically.

I tried this one

```
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi, 2);
        double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi, 2);
        double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

What else I found is, in Portrait and Landscape it returning different values.

and it's giving height probably, on my nexus it's 4.41 something. Any one have idea/suggestion here?

Comment: What you are doing seems correct. What device are you testing it on?

Comment: Got on my SGSIII 4.795398378933912, looks well.

Comment: Yes, I am testing on Nexus-4, but what I really want is Height and Width in terms of inch's...how can I get this.

Comment: i think you have check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193457/is-there-a-way-to-determine-android-physical-screen-height-in-cm-or-inches

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getRealSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(width/dm.xdpi, 2);
double y = Math.pow(height/dm.ydpi, 2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

Comment: it give dimension of screen, any other suggestion to get in inch.