# How to achieve density independence for devices in the same density bucket but different dpi?

Tags: android, layout, size, dpi

I am developing an Android app which I use `wrap_content`/`wrap_content` to set the `layout_width`/`layout_height` for many `ImageView`s. However, the  images look smaller on the Nexus5X (1920x1080 420dpi) than they appear on the Nexus5(1920x1080 480dpi). The two phones will use the same set of images in the `drawable-xxhdpi` bucket.

The question is:
is there a possible way to maintain the same physical sizes of images for devices in the same density bucket but different dpi?

Comment: show some code, how do you currently getting dimens/sizes? [this question might be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193457/is-there-a-way-to-determine-android-physical-screen-height-in-cm-or-inches)

Comment: I do not use any specific ways to get sizes. I just put some ImageViews in the layout and install apk to the two phones. Then I can see the images look physically smaller on the 5X.

Comment: The ways mentioned in the [Support Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) page seems to only explain how to achieve density independence across the density buckets. Should we just accept the fact that the physical size of dp and images might vary for devices in the same density bucket?

Comment: have you tried methods from linked question/answer in my previous comment? `DisplayMetrics` class have xdpi and ydpi for precise calculations. if you want to differ mentioned devices only with XML - it's not possible