# Calculating screen size

Tags: java, android

So I used this code to calculate screen size, but it returns wrong results.
It returns a screen size of `4'33"` but in reality the screen is `5'.0"`
So the value 4.33" corresponds to what? Current activity size?

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


        float height=metrics.heightPixels/metrics.xdpi;
        float width=metrics.widthPixels/metrics.ydpi;
```

And then, the view

```
 "The screen size is:"+(float)Math.sqrt(height*height+width*width) +"\n"
```

Comment: Bro, 5" might be physical size of screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to determine android physical screen height in cm or inches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193457/is-there-a-way-to-determine-android-physical-screen-height-in-cm-or-inches)

Comment: So 4,33 corresponds to what size? Acticity size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double instead of float and see the results. :)