# How to get physical size of the screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, size, flutter-dependencies

How to get the screen's (or pixel's) physical width and height in flutter?
is it possible?

I need to display exactly 1 cm on different screens programaticly

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get physical size of screen in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707923/get-physical-size-of-screen-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`MediaQuery.of(context).size`

```
 /// The size of the media in logical pixels (e.g, the size of the screen).
  ///
  /// Logical pixels are roughly the same visual size across devices. Physical
  /// pixels are the size of the actual hardware pixels on the device. The
  /// number of physical pixels per logical pixel is described by the
  /// [devicePixelRatio].
```

Comment: It is not a helpful answer.
I asked for the physical dimensions not for pixel counts.
I need to display exactly 1 cm on different screens programaticly.

Comment: Do you try that lib https://pub.dev/packages/sized_context ?